# Where is com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable located? (Android Studio)

Tags: android-studio, gradle, version, dex

In `build.gradle (Module:app)` my `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'` is underlined with red saying version mismatch with `com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable` (which apparently is v24). I cannot find anything named `vector-drawable` anywhere in the project though. The app won't start as long as the red marking remains, stating that it is unable to `merge dex`.

App grade looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'



android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.healthandchocolate.sjostedtafzelius.healthchocolateandroid"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

    }
}
}

dependencies {
//FIREBASE
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'

//GLIDE for images
/*
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.2.0'
kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-compat:27'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'
*/
compile 'com.master.android:glideimageview:1.0'

implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

//FORCES 27. RESOLVES VERSION CONFLICT
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.+'
    }
}
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably because of dependencies, (most probably your `com.master.android:glideimageview:1.0`, or maybe other).

So, just add another implementation that refer to animated-vector-drawable:

`implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1'`

Make sure to include `google()` repository in your top-level `build.gradle`